# Unable to install ZAP add-Ons (> Task :buildSrc:compileKotlin FAILED)

Tags: gradle, eclipse-plugin, git-bash, owasp, zap

Im having issues to install ZAP add ons using the command gradle tasks  after i put cd zaproxy. Im using windows, the goal is for me to plug in owasp zap in eclipse. I already have the owsap zap application installed using the installer x64 bit. Please help as i already referred the official tutorial documentation and youtube video but still couldnt solve the issue.

**What I did in gitbash:**
`NB MSI@KhairunAqilah-Laptop MINGW64 ~/zaproxy
$ gradle tasks
**What I should get:**
[image: the tutorial i followed]
**what i got:**

```
> Task :buildSrc:compileKotlin FAILED
The `kotlin-dsl` plugin applied to project ':buildSrc' enables experimental Kotlin compiler features. For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/META-INF/gradle.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of
 Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\build\generated-sources\kotlin-dsl-accessors\kotlin\gradle\kotlin\dsl\accessors\_e1186a2f8739d9ae78eab335915ef41a\Accessors26zbplfot43jvv3iww08bvstz.kt: (64, 66): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jTask' was compiled with an incompat
ible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jTask.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\build\generated-sources\kotlin-dsl-accessors\kotlin\gradle\kotlin\dsl\accessors\_e1186a2f8739d9ae78eab335915ef41a\Accessors26zbplfot43jvv3iww08bvstz.kt: (65, 40): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jTask' was compiled with an incompat
ible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jTask.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\build\generated-sources\kotlin-dsl-accessors\kotlin\gradle\kotlin\dsl\accessors\_e1186a2f8739d9ae78eab335915ef41a\Accessorsbmeqcrgd7c0p5ndnkkj10dxnn.kt: (64, 26): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jExtension' was compiled with an inc
ompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jExtension.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\build\generated-sources\kotlin-dsl-accessors\kotlin\gradle\kotlin\dsl\accessors\_e1186a2f8739d9ae78eab335915ef41a\Accessorsbmeqcrgd7c0p5ndnkkj10dxnn.kt: (65, 6): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jExtension' was compiled with an inco
mpatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jExtension.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\build\generated-sources\kotlin-dsl-accessors\kotlin\gradle\kotlin\dsl\accessors\_e1186a2f8739d9ae78eab335915ef41a\Accessorsbmeqcrgd7c0p5ndnkkj10dxnn.kt: (71, 26): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jExtension' was compiled with an inc
ompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jExtension.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\build\generated-sources\kotlin-dsl-accessors\kotlin\gradle\kotlin\dsl\accessors\_e1186a2f8739d9ae78eab335915ef41a\Accessorsbmeqcrgd7c0p5ndnkkj10dxnn.kt: (72, 6): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jExtension' was compiled with an inco
mpatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jExtension.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\build\generated-sources\kotlin-dsl-accessors\kotlin\gradle\kotlin\dsl\accessors\_e1186a2f8739d9ae78eab335915ef41a\Accessorsc7umvmbh1t2ps42oazl5v7ufw.kt: (64, 62): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jExtension' was compiled with an inc
ompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jExtension.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\build\generated-sources\kotlin-dsl-accessors\kotlin\gradle\kotlin\dsl\accessors\_e1186a2f8739d9ae78eab335915ef41a\Accessorsc7umvmbh1t2ps42oazl5v7ufw.kt: (65, 111): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jExtension' was compiled with an in
compatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jExtension.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\build\generated-sources\kotlin-dsl-accessors\kotlin\gradle\kotlin\dsl\accessors\_e1186a2f8739d9ae78eab335915ef41a\Accessorsc7umvmbh1t2ps42oazl5v7ufw.kt: (71, 79): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jExtension' was compiled with an inc
ompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jExtension.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\src\main\kotlin\org\zaproxy\zap\github-releases.gradle.kts: (3, 29): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jTask' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1
.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jTask.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\src\main\kotlin\org\zaproxy\zap\github-releases.gradle.kts: (103, 42): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jTask' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4
.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jTask.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\src\main\kotlin\org\zaproxy\zap\github-releases.gradle.kts: (105, 80): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jTask' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4
.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jTask.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\src\main\kotlin\org\zaproxy\zap\installers.gradle.kts: (3, 29): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jTask' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jTask.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\src\main\kotlin\org\zaproxy\zap\installers.gradle.kts: (109, 41): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jTask' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jTask.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\src\main\kotlin\org\zaproxy\zap\installers.gradle.kts: (110, 9): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jTask' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jTask.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\src\main\kotlin\org\zaproxy\zap\installers.gradle.kts: (111, 9): Class 'com.install4j.gradle.Install4jTask' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.4.1.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/NB MSI/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/gradle.plugin.install4j.install4j.buildtools/gradle_publish/10.0.3/508d4dda8e92616f1ad09cff9379b39812888f60/gradle_publish-10.0.3.jar!/com/install4j/gradle/Install4jTask.class
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\src\main\kotlin\org\zaproxy\zap\test.gradle.kts: (24, 10): Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
internal fun Project.sourceSets(configure: Action<SourceSetContainer>): Unit defined in gradle.kotlin.dsl.accessors._566dc064233c60a31df379898f991b12 in file Accessors2oadk7let745pm8ahqypkqzlk.kt
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\src\main\kotlin\org\zaproxy\zap\test.gradle.kts: (41, 32): Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
internal val Project.sourceSets: SourceSetContainer defined in gradle.kotlin.dsl.accessors._566dc064233c60a31df379898f991b12 in file Accessors2oadk7let745pm8ahqypkqzlk.kt
e: C:\Users\NB MSI\zaproxy\buildSrc\src\main\kotlin\org\zaproxy\zap\test.gradle.kts: (42, 26): Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
internal val Project.sourceSets: SourceSetContainer defined in gradle.kotlin.dsl.accessors._566dc064233c60a31df379898f991b12 in file Accessors2oadk7let745pm8ahqypkqzlk.kt

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildSrc:compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pulled the code recently then you may have got it in an inconsistent state as we were in the middle of releasing ZAP 2.12.0. Pull the code now and try again - it should be consistent and work.